# Finding the machine associated with an ip

Tags: router

Is it possible to find out if a public ip is associated with a router or a pc?

At my home i have internet connected to my pc through a netgear router. The router is connected to the internet 
modem. When i try to login to isp website through my router, i get authentication denied message. But if i connect 
my pc directly to modem the login passt hrough. I am not getting what difference the router can make?

I configured my router to use my pc mac address but still no avail.

Comment: i cannot login to superuser.com. How do i do that?

Comment: Contact your ISP, who will walk you through the basic configuration to get you connected.

Comment: Superuser details can be found here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 1):

A few have suggested using `nmap` to detect the OS on the machine. There is an additional hint that you can use, which is the OUI number issued. Of course, there is quite a lot of overlap between makers of routers and network cards for PCs. However, it is an additional hint to help. You can get the number as the first 3 bytes of the MAC address.

Comment: You can't get the MAC address beyong the first router.

Answer (score 0):

**nmap**

nmap will let you "crawl" an IP... so that could help shed some light on things for you.

It sounds to me though like you might have a firewall or port forwarding issue of some kind perhaps?

Perhaps the router is blocking you.  When you take the router out of the loop everything works as expected, right?

Comment: yes. The problem is only through router

Comment: Depending on your router type you may want to try CLONING the MAC ID of your cable modem to the router.

Answer (score 0):

`nmap` has a `-O` option that attempts to find the OS of the scanned device.

Don't run `nmap` against hardware where you don't have permission to run it, however.